How to log custom request headers in GCP Logs Explorer?
I am sending a request to a Cloud Run which first passes through a load balancer. The issue is that there is a custom header in the request but it is nowhere to be found in the logs. I looked into the logs of the Cloud Run as well as the load balancer but it's just not present.
I have tried to create custom headers using this guide (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers-global#console) where I added "user-email" as the custom header but this didn't work either.
The custom header is being removed by the load balancer or some other service because it works fine locally if I add the header and make a request and log that header from the backend. Is there any way to disable this behaviour?
I have tried sending the request from Postman as well as from code (Node.js):
const response = await fetch(
        `${apiUrl}`, { //This is hosted in GCP
          headers: {
            "User-Email": "random@user.com" //custom header
          }
        }
      );

